# In vba word how to skip execution on first 2 lines

Tags: vba, ms-word

When writing word macros, I find it useful to insert the launching command buttons on the first 2 lines, so to able to save the document and insert various texts anytime I need to for a local treatment.

For example, the following macro deletes all carriage returns in the document, and is linked to the command button "DelAllCRLF" that is located on the first line. When I press the button, it is deleted because the first line is treated as a carriage return, though it contains the button!

```
Private Sub DelAllCRLF_Click()
  ActiveDocument.Content = _
  Replace(ActiveDocument.Content, vbCr, " ")
End Sub
```

Please assist in making the macro begin execution from line 3 onward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the intent, and having the button on the ribbon instead seems like a better solution, but you can replace text starting from the third paragraph ( `vbCr` is paragraph separator ) :

```
ThisDocument.Range(ThisDocument.Paragraphs(3).Range.Start) _
    .Find.Execute vbCr, Replacewith:=" ", Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Application.ScreenRefresh ' optional
```

Comment: Thank you Slai this will do it!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not solved, but a workaround was found:
I now add a button to the Ribbon (or Excel 2003 toolbar in earlier versions) instead of putting them in the beginning of the document space, so they will not be deleted.

If I find a solution to the above initial question, i will post it.